# Sudoku, backtrack algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sudoku

Sudoku backtrack method

```
int xx = (pos.getX() / 3) * 3;          
int yy = (pos.getY() / 3) * 3;           
for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {              
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {               
        if ((xx + x != pos.getX()) && (yy + y != pos.getY())) {            
            possible[work[xx + x][yy + y]] = false;
```

where x and y =

```
private byte x;
private byte y;
```

Could someone explain why do we divide by three and multiply by three?

```
(pos.getY() / 3) * 3;                      
(pos.getX() / 3) * 3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The division is integer division so it will remove the remainder. Doing the integer division following by a multiplication will give the you the first cell index of the correct 3x3 block.

E.g.

```
pos    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8
/3     0    0    0    1    1    1    2    2    2
*3     0    0    0    3    3    3    6    6    6
```

Answer (score 1):

Because we want a multiple of 3. We want the greatest multiple of 3 that is less than pos.getX(). It corresponds to the upper-left cell in the current 3x3 square.

Remember X/3 must be an integer so (X/3)*3 may not be equal to X.